# Copying between 2 network mounted folders very slow

Tags: networking, mount, network-shares, docker, file-transfer

I have a NAS which has 4 volumes with shared folders. I have a Raspberry Pi 4 (running RPI OS Bullseye) which uses docker and various containers for various purposes. I have mounted essential network shares from my NAS in these containers as volumes to be accessible for various processes.

I have files which are stored on "NAS volume 1 - shared folder 1" and after a certain time they need to be moved to "NAS volume 2 - shared folder 2". This transfer is initiated from one of my docker containers on the Raspberry Pi automatically. The transfer of files this way takes excruciatingly long compared to if i simply copy the file manually on my windows PC from shared folder 1 to shared folder 2 where it takes a few minutes tops.

File system on the shared folders are the same as they are stored on the same NAS just on different drives.

I have searched for info to this and found that most likely reason is that since the remote client (RPI4) that initiates the copy from one remote folder to another doesn't know the file system of the mounted drives and as such probably copies the data bit by bit first to itself and retransfers it to the destination folder which is why it takes so much time.

I have tried to put these shared folders into a single aggregated "portal" folder on my NAS so that i can mount only that folder and in term that has subfolders which are linked to the shares on the different volumes. However this has also not improved the speed of the copy process.

So my question is: Is there a way i can somehow setup these remote network folders in a way that my remote client (RPI4) can initiate copying of files with same kind of performance as i have if i initiate the same operation from a windows PC client where it works flawlessly?

Comment: You mention the source and destination locations are on different drives. Is that “different” as in multiple physical HDDs or SSDs? How are these connected to your Raspberry Pi? How’s the CPU load when the operation is running?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to achieve this is by instead of making your Raspberry PI copy the files on your NAS from one folder to another, just make the NAS do the job on its own. There probably is some kind of software already installed on your NAS to do this kind of operation, but there is another way:

1. Install a ssh-client on your PI if there is not already a default
   one
2. Enable the ssh-server on your NAS
3. Write a script on your PI that
   copies / moves the wanted files and folders: It should look something like this
   `cp -r /path/to/foo /path/to/bar`
4. Make your PI run that script when you need it, e.g. using `cron`